# Is definability in $V$ in $\sf Ack+MK$ expressible in its language?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations, definability

Recall [Ackermann set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory). If we extend Ackermann's set theory by adding all axioms of $\sf MK$ to it. We shall denote the universe of all *elements* by $W$, while $V$ is the primitive constant symbol of Ackermann's set theory denoting the class of all *sets* [in Ackermann's sense].

Then can we express pure set theoretic definability in $V$ in this theory? That is, can we define the predicate $\operatorname {Vdefinable}_n$ to mean: is a subclass of $V$ that is definable after a set theoretic formula [i.e. not using the primitive constant $V$] from $n$ parameters in $V$? Formally:

$\operatorname {Vdefinable}_n(C) \iff C \subseteq V \land  \\\exists \phi \in \operatorname {formulas^{=,\in}} \land \exists x_1,..,x_n \in V : \\\forall y \, (y \in C  \iff y \in W \land W \models \phi(x_1,..,x_n,y) )$

The reason why I need that, is to turn the $\omega$-inference rule presented in this prior [posting](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425342/whats-the-consistency-strength-of-adding-this-inference-rule-to-ackermanns-set), into ordinary schema.

So first we define:

$\operatorname {Def}_n(V) = \{ C \subseteq V^n \mid \operatorname {Vdefinable}_n (C) \}$,

then we schematize:$$ \forall C \in \operatorname {Def}_n(V) \, \phi \implies \forall C \in \mathcal P(V^n) \, \phi$$; where $\phi$ has all its quantifier's bounded $\in V$, and $V$ doesn't occur in it otherwise, and has only $C$ occurring free.

This schema copies the line of thought about founding Category theory in sets paraphrased as *having our cake and eating it too* (see [Shulman's: Set theory for Category theory. P 27: Strong Reflection Principles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.1279.pdf))